# How Describe all duplicate string or number without remove duplicate in C#

Tags: c#

> if i input string or number.
>
> > Example Input : 02x2, 05x3, 05x3, 02x4, 19.02x21, 21.02x3

> I want ouput :
> 02x2
> 02x4
> 05x3
> 05x3
> 02x3
> 02x21

Helpme

Comment: why 02x21 is not in your output? can you please explain? or you want remove decimal number from string.

Comment: @PawanLakhara Sorry, I made a typo and I changed the output. i don't want to remove double characters, but i want to see the output, any characters that are double. Please help me

Comment: duplicate? i saw something more, for instance `21.02x3` turns into `02x3`. is the extraction for it already covered? if yes, you can use [`HashSet`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1?view=net-6.0) to chug in your strings into. the `HashSet` will make sure there is no duplicate entry. also, what you have tried? we eager to help, but stackoverflow is not a code generator service. please have a tour on [ask]. cheers!

Comment: @BagusTesa thanks bro, but I'm confused about what the algorithm looks like. I've tried it, the result still displays a single character only. I want the output to be able to describe duplicate characters

Comment: @BagusTesa, Terimakasih sarannya bro, tapi saya sedang bingung seperti apa bentuk algoritma nya. saya sudah mencobanya, hasilnya tetap menampilkan karakter tunggal saja. saya mau hasil outputnya bisa menjabarkan karakter yang duplikat.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
string str = "02x2, 05x3, 05x3, 02x4, 19.02x21, 21.02x3";
var str1 = str.Split(',');
string test = "";
List<string> strs = new List<string>();
foreach (var item in str1.OrderBy(x => x.Trim()))
{
     var str2 = item.Split('x');
     string i = "";
    
     if (str2[0].ToString().Contains("."))
     {
      var st = str2[0].ToString().Split('.');
      i = st[st.Count() -1];
     }
     else
     {
       i = str2[0].ToString();
     }
  test += i.ToString() + 'x' + str2[1].ToString() + ",";
}
test.TrimEnd(',');
```

Output : 02x2, 02x4, 05x3, 05x3,02x21,02x3

Comment: Thank you bro, this succesfull. if there is another method, you can answer at any time. the rest i thank you

Comment: there is a slight problem when I try your code, where the input still doesn't match the output. I also replaced the input with another one and the output is different.

Comment: My input : 11x8,22.33.44.55.66x3,22.44.66x4,22.x2,55x3,66.44x2,55x3,33x3,33x3,22x3,33,55x3,5x2,66x50 and output  error

Comment: should be, the output is like this, Output : 22x3,22x4,22x2,22x3,44x3,44x4,44x2,33x3,33x3,33x333x3,55x3,55x3,55x3,55x3,66x3,66x4,66x2,66x50

Comment: Please check updated answer, may be above syntax will be wrong , please try st[st.count -1] or st[st.count()-1 ] or st[st.length -1]

Comment: okay bro, I'll try and I'll tell you the rest of the results. Thank You

Comment: theek hai bhaee, main koshish karoonga aur main aapako baakee parinaam bataoonga. dhanyavaad